# Any reproducible r code for week day effect in garch?

Tags: garch

I am looking for an r code to run a GARCH model with a day of week effect. Is there any package or code I can use for this?

Comment: Use `rugarch` package in R. Relevant functions are `ugarchspec` with the option `external.regressors` (you supply day-of-the-week dummies there) and `ugarchfit`. You may find some examples in the packages vignette or on the author's website. Not necessarily an example with dummies specifically but perhaps with some other kind of external regressors.

Comment: Thank you @RichardHardy  I will look into that